# Pandas .loc doesn't find null values based on .isnull() boolean array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get info about the null-values in my DF column `LotFrontage`. As you can see, there are some of them, confirmed in 2 ways:

```
hp_lot = houseprices[['LotFrontage', 'LotArea']]
hp_lot.describe()
hp_lot.info()
```

output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2919 entries, 1 to 2919
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------       --------------  -----  
 0   LotFrontage  2433 non-null   float64
 1   LotArea      2919 non-null   int64  
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 68.4 KB
```

```
houseprices_num['LotFrontage'].isnull().describe()
```

output:

```
count      2919
unique        2
top       False
freq       2433
```

But when I'm trying to locate them, I'm just getting this:

```
lf_null = houseprices_num.loc[houseprices_num['LotFrontage'].isnull(), ['LotFrontage']]
lf_null.describe()
```

output:

```
count    0.0
mean     NaN
std      NaN
min      NaN
25%      NaN
50%      NaN
75%      NaN
max      NaN
Name: LotFrontage, dtype: float64
```

My question is where the hell are my null-values? And if I messed up something in the syntax, why am I not getting an error message of some kind?

The variables:

```
traindf = pd.read_csv('.\\train.csv', sep=',', header=1, index_col='Id')
testdf = pd.read_csv('.\\test.csv', sep=',', header=0, index_col='Id')
houseprices = pd.concat([traindf, testdf], axis=0)
houseprices_num = houseprices[['LotFrontage', 'LotArea', 'MasVnrArea', 'BsmtFinSF1', 'BsmtFinSF2', 'BsmtUnfSF',
                              'TotalBsmtSF', '1stFlrSF', '2ndFlrSF', 'LowQualFinSF', 'GrLivArea', 'GarageArea', 'WoodDeckSF', 'OpenPorchSF', 'EnclosedPorch',
                              '3SsnPorch', 'ScreenPorch', 'PoolArea', 'MiscVal', 'SalePrice']]
```

Comment: you have many different variables, houseprices, hp_lot, houseprices_num. Please can you share the entire code so that I can better understand the issue.

Comment: houseprices_num is the numerical subset of houseprices

Comment: that still is vague, without looking at the data or the code it would very hard to provide a correct solution, never the less I have provided one, please review it and if it helps mark the answer as accepted. It will be help me out a lot. Have a great day!

Comment: I added the origin of the variables. I hope that it helps.

Comment: Can you try to run the following,  
```
lf_null = houseprices_num.loc[houseprices_num['LotFrontage'].isnull()]
lf_null.head()
```

Comment: Yes, the output is a subset of houseprices_null, the LotFrontage values are all null as expected, but I cant comment the output here, because it exceeds the character limit of comments.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is with this line

```
lf_null = houseprices_num['LotFrontage'].loc[houseprices_num['LotFrontage'].isnull()]
lf_null.describe()
```

You need to use loc in the following way

```
lf_null = houseprices_num.loc[houseprices_num['LotFrontage'].isnull(), ['LotFrontage']]
lf_null.describe()
```

Comment: I corrected this mistake, although the original code should have worked too, since originally the .loc was called on a Series, but the output is still the same.

Comment: @danbuza It might have something to do with the transformation you applied to get to houseprices_num, can you share the part of the code which gets you from houseprices to housprices_num